# Very simple adapter rearrangement technic in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a search engine that perform search in a pre-defined strings. I want to show the list of the result in a custom font rather then android default! I also have a simple custom font app. But cannot make a good adapter for this.

This is Custom Font App

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(cFont);




<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:id="@+id/tv"
/>
```

This is product search app:

public class ProductList extends Activity {

```
   // List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

    String asim02 = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String products[] = {
            "Apple" + asim02 +"Definition1", 
            "Orange" + asim02 +"Definition2",
            "Banana"+ asim02 +"Definition3", 
            "Onion"+ asim02 +"Definition4", };


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.p_list,   products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);




<TextView

        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/p_list"
        />
```

Please help to make the adapter!!! I am very new and cannot understand well!!! Want your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Custom ListView Adapter for this and set the font in its getView method.

Some Tutorials:
[Tutorial 1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)
[More Tuts](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/)

Comment: Boss Please explain me in details. It would be great if you kindly give me the code directly. I am very new to android.

Comment: This is not a place to give code but to give directions. I have added the links to tutorials which can be followed.

Comment: Then you should start learning Android. This is not the place to spoon-feed you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use use custom adapter as Pravin suggested. In getview() method you have to set the font for the texview. You have to place  your TrueType (TTF) or even OpenType file (OTF) fonts in to the assets folder within your project.

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myfontfile);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/CHOCD.otf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);
```

You can view more details in the following link http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-font-example